# Narrowing a dataset down by string pattern

Tags: dataset

For `dataset`

```
dataset = Dataset[{
   <|"a" -> "apple1", "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
   <|"a" -> "apple2", "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
   <|"a" -> "banana", "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>}]
```

How does one filter/narrow this dataset down to entries whose `"a"` field matches some *string pattern*, for example the string pattern `"apple*"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
dataset[Select[StringMatchQ[#a, "apple*"] &]]
```

[image]

Also

```
Query[Select[StringMatchQ[#a, "apple*"] &]] @ dataset
```

> same result

Comment: Is there a way to make this search -- not against just `#a` -- but against *all* fields in an (arbitrary) Dataset? (Similar to piping a string through `grep` in a shell console)?

Comment: maybe `dataset[Cases[KeyValuePattern[_ -> _String?(StringMatchQ["apple*"])]]]` or `dataset[Select[
  Not@*FreeQ[KeyValuePattern[_ -> _String?(StringMatchQ["apple*"])]]]]`?

Comment: ... also `dataset[Select[
  MatchQ[KeyValuePattern[_ -> _String?(StringMatchQ["apple*"])]]]]`